# How to join a table to two separate grouped sub-queries?

Tags: t-sql

So this is a very strange circumstance but I need to figure out how to join two select statements. I have two select statements returning a list of "filekeys" (employee identifiers) and that's it, each one is just one column and I want to return a list with all the filekeys. There can be duplicates or not, it doesn't matter to me.

Now normally I'd just adjust what's in my where statment but I can't get that to work, so maybe that's the answer, here is (a very basic version) of what's going on

```
select yt.filekey from EMPLOYEES yt
inner join (
select filekey, SUM(hours) as test 
from PAYDESHIST 
where WG2 = 1
and eventdate between (date1) and (date2)
group by filekey having SUM(hours) > 40)
ss on yt.FILEKEY = ss.FILEKEY
```

There is a second one of these with different dates

Basically I need to see if the employees have worked more than 40 hours in one or more of two weeks. It doesn't matter if an employee worked more than 40 hours in both of the weeks, it will all be filtered down later to one list.

I've tried full join but I just get null for every employee that worked over 40 hours for one of those weeks.

Please help!
Thanks

Also, there may be a couple errors in the code, that isn't the problem, the errors are because the actual call is MUCH longer to get those dates and with all sorts of crazy stuff so in copying it over I may have missed a parenthesis or something.

Comment: Yes you want inner join not full join. So can you elaborate on your statement "but I can't get that to work." or provide some sample data?

Comment: @Martin
Inner join don't provide enough results, I think it only provides employees who worked more than 40 hours in both weeks. I can't get that to work means I have NO idea how to use having, I could say `where eventdate between (date1) and (date2) or eventdate between (date3) and (date4) group by filekey having sum(hours) > 40` but that would return employees who had worked more than 40 hours over the course of 2 weeks, I don't know how to us having such that I could specify. Does that make sense?

Comment: in that case try to UNION the two date range queries, then inner join to the combined query

Comment: @Martin
Fantastic! That worked, that is so obvious I don't know how I missed it. I feel like an idiot. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It appears the answer would be something like this:

```
select yt.filekey from EMPLOYEES yt
inner join (
    select filekey, test from (
        select filekey, SUM(hours) as test 
        from PAYDESHIST 
        where WG2 = 1
        and eventdate between (date1) and (date2)
        group by filekey having SUM(hours) > 40)
        ss on yt.FILEKEY = ss.FILEKEY)
        union all
        select filekey, SUM(hours) as test 
        from PAYDESHIST 
        where WG2 = 1
        and eventdate between (date3) and (date4)
        group by filekey having SUM(hours) > 40)
        ss on yt.FILEKEY = ss.FILEKEY)
    )
)
```

Based on our comments discussion